# An new arranging of the discrete Sine transforms

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, transform, cosine

Let $n$ be even and  consider the non-normalized discrete Sine transform of type 5 which is

$$S=\left(\sin(k+1)(l+1)\frac{\pi}{n+\frac12}\right)_{k,l=0}^{n-1}$$

Let us denote $s_{-,l}$ by  the $l^{th}$-column  of $S$. It can be considered as a $n$-tuple in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Q.**  I am looking for $n$-tuples $v=(v_0,\cdots,v_{n-1})$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the following conditions:

1-  $v_j=\sin2(j+1)\frac{\pi}{n+\frac12}$ if $j$ is even.

2- The following  are valid concerning inner products: $$\langle v , s_{-,l} \rangle=\left\{
  \begin{array}{cl}
     1 & l=0 \\
    0 & l\neq 0~,~  l \operatorname{is even}
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: is this a spectral leakage question?

Answer (score 3):

Let's restate your problem as a linear equation

Let $U_{ee}$, $U_{eo}$, $U_{oe}$, $U_{oo}$ be the partition of the $S$ matrix in even-odd row-column index, similarly $v_e$ and $v_o$ are the partitions of $v$.

Restating your conditions in terms of matrices

1 - $v_e$ is fixed

2 - $v_e U_{ee} + v_o U_{oe} = I_1$, where $I_1$ denotes the first row of the identity matrix.

Placing all the constant terms on the right side of the condition 2, $v_o U_{oe} = (I_1 - v_e U_{ee})$, transposing we get a linear equation system in the standard form $U_{oe}^{T} v_o = (I_1 - v_e U_{ee})^T$

#### Proof that $U_{oe}$ has no pair of linearly dependent columns

Assuming

$s_{2i+1, 2j} = \sin\left( \frac{2\pi (2i+2)(2j+1)}{2n+1} \right)$

Two columns will be linearly dependent if, and only if, there are two integers $0 \le j_1, j_2 \le n/2-1$, for all integer  $0 \le i \le n/2-1$

$$(2i+2)(2j_1 + 1) \equiv (2i+2)(2j_2 + 1) \operatorname{mod} (2n+1), $$

$$(2j_1 + 1) \equiv (2j_2 + 1) \operatorname{mod} (2n+1)$$

$$j_1 \equiv j_2 \operatorname{mod} (2n+1)$$

since both $j_1$ and $j_2$ are positive integers, smaller than $2n+1$, the condition can only be satisfied with $j_1 = j_2$, thus the matrix $U_{oe}$ is non-singular.

Comment: That is a nice approach, but seems there is only a gap! How can we sure that the entries in the diagonal of the upper triangular matrix  $R$ are all non-zero?

Comment: If the rows of the input matrix are linearly independent, the diagonal elements are non-zero. I will add more details.

Comment: Yes, and so  the **proof**  linear independency will be equivalent to find the vector $q$.

Comment: To be honest I couldn't unambiguously parse your equation, do you mean $$s_{k,l} = \sin\left(\frac{(k+1)(l+1)\pi}{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: I expressed in terms of a linear equation, the necessary and sufficient condition for a solution to exist is that $s_{k,l}$ for odd $k$ and even $l$ must be non-singular. Bear with me, and double check if I didn't mess with the indices ;)

Comment: Yes, non-singularity is the necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: So, is the answer acceptable?

Comment: I could not get analytic proof for the  non-singularity of $U_{oe}$ yet!

Comment: Is my parsing of the sin expression above correct?

Comment: No,  $n+\frac{1}{2}$ should be in the denominator.

Comment: My typo. Check the proof in the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140821/discussion-between-abb-and-bob).

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** for any other reader not familiar with **DST** type 5 or **DST-V**, I'd like to include the definition of **Discrete Sine Transform** and types.

Following a list with **DST** types 1 to 5, from

https://planetmath.org/discretesinetransform

[image]

[1D DST types 1st to 8th](https://planetmath.org/discretesinetransform)

**2.-** Bob's assumption is correct. The question expression

[image]

actually means

[image]

and I'd like to add that the question expression for **DST-V**

[image]

is this

[image]

**3.-** **DST Discrete Sine Transform** and the counterpart **DCT Discrete Cosine Transform** are just partials of the **DFT Discrete Fourier Transform**.

Like Wolfram concisely explains here

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html

and here

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Leakage.html

**Unless the signal or signal fragment is periodic in the watched interval, there's always (spectral) leakage.**

**4.-** So, if the unknown input signal were all ones, satisfying the 2 conditions in the question would go the  Bob answered.

**5.-** Yet it is up to `x(:)*sin((k+1)*(L+1)*pi/(N+1))` not just the term `sin((k+1)*(L+1)*pi/(N+1)` to meet the non-leakage condition mentioned in point 2.

And since `x` is not supplied in the question in any shape or manner. there's no way to tell without knowing `x` .

**5.- Is this a MATLAB question anyway?**

I politely suggest this question to be moved to a Stack Overflow Maths page, or to for instance `signal analysis` or `sampling` tags in this same Signal Processing page

Thanks for reading.